# How to make Intellisense Quick Info for JavaScript and CSS files to appear in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, quickinfo

In Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, when I edit a JavaScript or CSS file, the Intellisense Quick Info for Members, Objects and other keywords don't appear. However, when I open the same files in Visual Studio Code 1.66.0, Intellisense Quick Info is shown properly. This results in me failing to interpret the significance of JS and CSS functions and keywords, hence, causing a ream of inconvenience to me. Why is this happening and how can I make Quick Info appear properly for JS and CSS files in Visual Studio 2017? Any help on this matter is greatly complimented.

Regards

Please take a look at the screenshots below:

VS Code showing Quick Info for `response.cookie()` method in JS file
[image: VS Code showing Quick Info for JS file]

Visual Studio 2017 not showing Quick Info for the same JS file
[image: Visual Studio 2017 not showing Quick Info for the same JS file]

VS Code showing Quick Info for `background-attachment` property in CSS file
[image: VS Code showing Quick Info for CSS file]

Visual Studio 2017 not showing Quick Info for the same CSS file
[image]

Comment: Please consider using Visual Studio 2022 instead of Visual Studio 2017, at least it will show Quick Info for background-attachment property. 